# How to select right values in JSON file in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, rdd

I got a json file similar to this.

```json
"code": 298484,
"details": {
    "date": "0001-01-01",
    "code" : 0
}
```

`code` appears twice, one is filled and the other one is empty. I need the first one with the data in details. What is the approach in pyspark?

I tried to filter

```
df = rdd.map(lambda r: (r['code'], r['details'])).toDF()
```

But it shows `_1, _2` (no schema).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
spark.read.json("path to json").select("code", "details.date")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30641514)

Comment: @kkakkurt: This is clearly making a suggestion. It'd be a better answer if it came with an explanation of what it's doing and why the author thinks it might solve the problem. But that's a reason to downvote it, if you feel so inclined, not to delete it.

Comment: That said, Benny, this is a good lesson to state answers declaratively. Asking "Have you tried this?" or "What about this?" might get mistaken as a new question or, at minimum, a clarifying question. (It shouldn't, but reviewers sometimes go too quickly, and mistake rhetorical questions as actual questions.) I've edited your question to clarify this.